# jQuery function to activate method onclick?

Tags: c#, jquery, mysql, forms, asp.net-mvc-4

On click, I want my button to execute the `startAjax` function, which sends the form data to the server via an AJAX POST request.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function startAjax() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("Submit", "CreateController")',
                    data: $('#PrivateUser').serialize(),
                    datatype: "json",
                    success: $("Submit1").click(function (data) {
                        $('#result').html(data)
                    })
                });
            }
        </script>
        <button type="button" id="Submit1" value="Submit" onclick="startAjax()">Opret Bruger</button>
```

This is what I am using on the back end to store the data in the database:

```
 public static MySqlConnection GetConnection(string host, string user, string pwd, string db)
    {
        string conStr = string.Format("server={0};uid={1};pwd={2};database={3}", host, user, pwd, db);
        var con = new MySqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = conStr;
        con.Open();
        return con;
    }

    public static MySqlConnection GetDefaultConnection()
    {
        return GetConnection("localhost", "root", "", "EventCrush");
    }

    public ActionResult Submit(string Fornavn, string Efternavn, string Email, int Telfonnummer, string Brugernavn, byte Avatar, string Kodeord, DateTime Fødselsdag)
    {
        var con = GetDefaultConnection();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into Private_User values (@Username, @PW, @Birthdate, @FirstName, @LastName, @Eamail, @PhoneNumber)";
        cmd.Prepare();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Brugernavn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PW", Kodeord);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Birthdate", Fødselsdag);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", Fornavn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", Efternavn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", Email);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhoneNumber", Telfonnummer);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (con != null) { con.Close(); }
        return View();
    }
```

I am not getting any errors, but the data isn't getting stored in the database. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "EventCrush - Registrer Privatbruger";
}

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 right-content"><img src="/Content/img/logo.png" class="animated bounceInDown"></div>
        <div class="col-md-8 center-content">
            <h3 class="">Opret Konto</h3><br>
            <span>
                Med en bruger på EventCrush får du flere muligheder, som f.eks. muligheden for at oprette events!<br>
                Det tager kun 2 minutter, så er du klar!
            </span>
            <br /><br />
            <a href="@Url.Action("CorporateUser","Create")" class="button button-big"><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/ui-icon/corporate-w.png")" style="height:35px;margin-top:-6px;" /> Erhvervskunde, tryk her!</a>
            <br /><br />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <form id="PrivateUser">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="sr-only">Fornavn</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control-1" placeholder="Fornavn *" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="sr-only">Efternavn</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control-1" placeholder="Efternavn *" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="sr-only">Email</label>
                    <input type="Email" class="form-control-1" placeholder="Email *" required>
                </div>
                <script>    $('.datepicker').datepicker({ language: "da", orientation: "bottom auto" });</script>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="sr-only">Fødselsdag</label>
                    <input class="datepicker form-control-1" placeholder="Fødselsdag *" required data-provide="datepicker" data-date-clearbtn="true" data-date-autoclose="true" data-date-format="mm/dd/yyyy">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="sr-only">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control-1" placeholder="Kodeord *">
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only">Vejnavn</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control-1" placeholder="Vejnavn *">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only">Vejnummer</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control-1" placeholder="Vejnummer *">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only">By</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control-1" placeholder="By *">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only">Postnummer</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control-1" placeholder="Postnummer *" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only">Land</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control-1" placeholder="Land *">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only">Telefonnummer</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control-1" placeholder="Telefonnummer">
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function startAjax() {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: '@Url.Action("Submit", "CreateController")',
                        data: $('#PrivateUser').serialize(),
                        datatype: "json",
                        success: $("Submit1").click(function (data) {
                            $('#result').html(data)
                        })
                    });
                }
            </script>
            <button type="button" id="Submit1" value="Submit" onclick="startAjax()">Opret Bruger</button>
            * Skal udfyldes
        </div>
        </form>

        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Content: End -->
```

EDIT - Rendered HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>EventCrush - Registrer Privatbruger - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
    <link href="/Content/eventcrushcss/css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script src="/Scripts/eventcrushjs/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/eventcrushjs/jquerymin.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/eventcrushjs/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/eventcrushjs/bootstrapmin.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/eventcrushjs/fileinputmin.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/eventcrushjs/headroom.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/eventcrushjs/jQuery.headroommin.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/eventcrushjs/bootstrap-datepickerdamin.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/eventcrushjs/bootstrap-datepickermin.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/eventcrushjs/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

    <!-- JQ -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>

    <body>
        <!-- Top Header: Start-->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top animated fadeIn">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <li><a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="/Content/img/logo.png" class="animated fadeIn" style="height:35px;" /></a></li>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target=".login-modal" href="#"><img src="/Content/img/ui-icon/login-g.png" style="height:20px;"> Login</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="/Home/Search_Event"><img src="/Content/img/ui-icon/search-g.png" style="height:20px;" /> Find Event</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/Create/PrivateUser"><img src="/Content/img/ui-icon/user-g.png" style="height:20px;" />Opret Konto / Opret Event</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <!-- Top-Header: End -->
        <!-- Login Modal: Start -->
        <div class="modal fade login-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm center-content" style="margin-top:200px;">
                <div class="modal-content" style="padding:30px;">
                    <h2>Velkommen tilbage</h2>
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only">Email</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control-1" placeholder="Email" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only">Kodeord</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control-1" placeholder="Kodeord" required>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="button">Login</button>
                        <a href="#" class="button">Glemt Kodeord?</a> <br><br>
                        <a href="create-event.php" class="button">Admin Login</a>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 right-content"><img src="/Content/img/logo.png" class="animated bounceInDown"></div>
        <div class="col-md-8 center-content">
            <h3 class="">Opret Konto</h3><br>
            <span>
                Med en bruger på EventCrush får du flere muligheder, som f.eks. muligheden for at oprette events!<br>
                Det tager kun 2 minutter, så er du klar!
            </span>
            <br /><br />
            <a href="/Create/CorporateUser" class="button button-big"><img src="/Content/img/ui-icon/corporate-w.png" style="height:35px;margin-top:-6px;" /> Erhvervskunde, tryk her!</a>
            <br /><br />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <form id="PrivateUser">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="sr-only">Fornavn</label>
                    <input name="Fornavn" type="text" class="form-control-1" placeholder="Fornavn *" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="sr-only">Efternavn</label>
                    <input name="Efternavn" type="text" class="form-control-1" placeholder="Efternavn *" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="sr-only">Email</label>
                    <input name="Email" type="Email" class="form-control-1" placeholder="Email *" required>
                </div>
                <script>    $('.datepicker').datepicker({ language: "da", orientation: "bottom auto" });</script>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="sr-only">Fødselsdag</label>
                    <input name="Fødselsdag" class="datepicker form-control-1" placeholder="Fødselsdag *" required data-provide="datepicker" data-date-clearbtn="true" data-date-autoclose="true" data-date-format="mm/dd/yyyy">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="sr-only">Password</label>
                    <input name="Password" type="password" class="form-control-1" placeholder="Kodeord *">
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only">Vejnavn</label>
                <input name="Vejnavn" type="text" class="form-control-1" placeholder="Vejnavn *">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only">Vejnummer</label>
                <input name="Vejnummer" type="number" class="form-control-1" placeholder="Vejnummer *">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only">By</label>
                <input name="By" type="text" class="form-control-1" placeholder="By *">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only">Postnummer</label>
                <input name="Postnummer" type="text" class="form-control-1" placeholder="Postnummer *" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only">Land</label>
                <input name="Land" type="text" class="form-control-1" placeholder="Land *">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only">Telefonnummer</label>
                <input name="Telefonnummer" type="number" class="form-control-1" placeholder="Telefonnummer">
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $("#Submit1").on("click", function (e) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: '/CreateController/Submit',
                        data: $('#PrivateUser').serialize(),
                        datatype: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            $('#result').html(data)
                        }
                    });
                    e.preventDefault(); //prevent the form from submitting
                });
            </script>
            <button type="button" id="Submit1" value="Submit">Opret Bruger</button>
            * Skal udfyldes
        </div>
        </form>

        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Content: End -->
        <!-- Footer: Start -->
        <div style="height:800px"></div>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").headroom();
    </script>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">window.__vwd_mapping_data={"map":[{"sourceFile":"~/Views/Create/PrivateUser.cshtml"},{"sourceFile":"~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"}]};</script>
<!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/__vwd/js/artery"></script>
<!-- End Browser Link -->
</html>
```

Comment: That looks fine on a first pass. Why do you think something isn't working? Are you getting errors?

Comment: Because nothing is passed to the Database :-S

No errors

Comment: Could you please post the HTML?

Comment: What is it you are trying to do with `success:`? Your syntax is wrong for that parameter, and confusing me. It sounds like you might not need the `success` option at all.

Comment: Posted HTML now..

dave - im not the strongest, so this i what i got from reading all the topics a could concerning this :-s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the syntax in your ajax call, specifically, your `submit` parameter. Additionally, you are losing the benefit of an AJAX call, because HTML will automatically submit your form when you click the button.

You should remove the inline event from your button:

```
<button type="button" id="Submit1" value="Submit">Opret Bruger</button>
```

Then assign the event handler in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Submit1").on("click", function(e) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("Submit", "Create")',
            data: $('#PrivateUser').serialize(),
            datatype: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#result').html(data)
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault(); //prevent the form from submitting
    });
});
```

That `e.preventDefault();` will prevent your page from submitting (you don't need to do it again you already did it through AJAX). Or you could use an `<input type="button">` which won't auto submit the form.

Comment: Just tried that, still nothing getting to my database.. It's like my Submit method is never reached :(

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in your Submit action, does it break there? Also, it might help if you posted the rendered HTML (from the browser), not the Razor syntax.

Comment: It did not break :(

I posted the renderes HTML :)

Comment: Ah, I missed it the first time. You should be using `url: '@Url.Action("Submit", "Create")'`. MVC assumes the controller will be suffixed with "Controller".

Comment: Still does not break at the Submit method, so something is still wrong :(

Comment: Use the [Chrome network tab](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network#network-panel-overview) to see what status you get back from the AJAX call

Comment: [Screenshot](http://i58.tinypic.com/b4c2l4.png) here a screeshot of the Network tap. Looks like the AJAX is nit running.

Comment: Perhaps add your javascript inside a `$(document).ready()` as I have shown in the updated answer. If that still fails, add an alert just before the ajax call and see if that is triggered.

Comment: Thank you Dave, you solved it with that one! 

Now my problem is the form info is noget passed, so its back to googling and trying to solve that.. But thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem stems from your Ajax, the URL appears to be incorrect.  It should be the following, to properly hit your Controller:

```
/Home/Validate
```

- *Home*, would be the Controller.
- *Validate*, would be the request within the Controller.

Once you call that, it should resolve as intended.

Comment: so url: '/CreateController/Submit',

Or 

Excactly /home/Validate as you write it... im not the brightes jQuery head :D

Comment: I don't think that [`@Url.Action`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492758(v=vs.118).aspx) is causing the problem. That's the Razor syntax which should create a fully qualified URL.

Comment: @dave That is true, sometimes the Fully qualified doesn't correlate correctly for Ajax.